# Custom BackgroundConverter for LongListSelector

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, ivalueconverter

I have a specific color scheme in my app and i wan't my `LongListSelectors` Jump List Style to be exactly match my color scheme, I have created the Style for the JumpList and its like this.

```
<Style x:Name="LibraryJumpListStyle" TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Background="#007fb3" Margin="6" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" FontSize="48" Margin="12,0,0,0" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="LayoutMode" Value="Grid"/>
    <Setter Property="GridCellSize" Value="111,111"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12,6,0,0"/>
</Style>
```

But this makes all my jump list items including disabled(Sections where i don't have any items) the same color. I want the disabled jumplist items to be different color. I understand  for this i need to make my own BackgroundConverter. But the problem is i don't know where to start or how to. What parameters i need to pass. I know how valuse Converters work and have wrote some converters myself. But here i don;t have a clue. I have searched and have not found any sample code where i can use as a base for my custom BackgroundConverter. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Hey KasunKV have you considering hiding empty groups instead?  Like so,

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="accounts_ls" IsGroupingEnabled="True" HideEmptyGroups="true"/>
```

If you're dead set on the disabled color then take a look at this; it's too much code to repeat here:

[Change-the-background-of-a-border-with-converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243252/wp7-change-the-background-of-a-border-with-converter)

If you're using a GroupKeyList for your groups then your IsPair will need to check the size of group and return a color when the size is empty (0) and another color when it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;

public class ColorResolver : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
       return GetColorFromHexa((string) value)); 
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private SolidColorBrush GetColorFromHexa(string hexaColor)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(
            Color.FromArgb(
                255,
                Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(1, 2), 16),
                Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(3, 2), 16),
                Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(5, 2), 16)
            )
        );
     }
}
```

Bind the color you want to be applied to the Border.

```
<Border Background="{Binding MyColorProperty, Converter={StaticResource MyColorConverter}}" Margin="6" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" FontSize="48" Margin="12,0,0,0" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</Border>
```

This is a WinRT implementation. Just replace the GetColorFromHexa() method with a suitable WP8 method to convert the color.Seperate the Method from the converter, So you could re use it. That's it! :)